# Magento Rule-Based Product Relations Disappear After Save at Product Level?

Tags: php, magento

We are running Magento Enterprise edition and have noticed that the "Rule-Based Product Relations" dissapear from the product pages when that particular product is saved in the admin. We have set up relationships such as an "HDMI Cable" tied to anything with an attribute of "HDMI Input: Yes," yet when we edit say a TV and hit save the Recommended Accessory vanishes from that TVs product page. We have found that when we go into the "Related Products" rule for the category of HDMI cables that are supposed to be populating the product pages, and hit the "Save Rule" button the cable will then re-appear on the above-mentioned TV page. The possibility for us to have thousands of these types of rules is pretty good, and the thought of having to go through each rule and manually save them is a little ominous? Does anyone have any thoughts on a way to get the rules to refresh on a regular basis? Any help is greatly appreciated!